# How to implement LLL Lattice Reduction in NTL using c++?

Tags: c++, ntl, mathematical-lattices

I am using C++ to do a research. And I am interested to know how to use the LLL function in NTL to find the shortest vector. My code is as follow;

```
#include <NTL/ZZ.h>
#include <NTL/matrix.h>
#include <NTL/mat_ZZ.h>
#include <NTL/vector.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace NTL;

int main()
{
    Mat<ZZ> B;
    cin >> B;
    cout << B << "\n";
    long LLL(ZZ& det2, mat_ZZ& B, long verbose = 0);
    cout << B << "\n";
}
```

However, the matrix I enter into B is not reduced. What is wrong?

Comment: This was the second Google result for me, does this help? http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/LLL.cpp.html

Comment: Thank you. I found it too. It is a documentation, but it does not have a sample of how to implement LLL Algorithm correctly.

Comment: Just as a side note: LLL does not find the shortest lattice vector. It computes only a better lattice basis consisting of short vectors and often containing a shortest vector. But this is not guaranteed. To be sure you need to search for the shortest vector using Enum oder NewEnum algorithm but I think both are not implemented in NTL.

Answer (score 0):

I realise I have forgotten to include the correct library and implementation of LLL is not correct.

This is the library that I have forgotten to include.

```
#include <NTL/LLL/h>
```

To execute LLL algorithm, do as follow

```
LLL_XD(B);
```